# grep or other regexp to get value of output

Tags: linux, debian, regex, grep

How to use `grep` or any other tool to get a specific value in an output

In the below output I need to get the value `255.00` in the line with `Minimum:                   255.00 (1.0000)`

A pattern like: `Channel Statistics:\s+Gray:\s+Minimum: +([\d.]+)`

```
Image: test.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Geometry: 2525x1785
  Class: DirectClass
  Type: bilevel
  Depth: 1 bits-per-pixel component
  Channel Depths:
    Gray:     1 bits
  Channel Statistics:
    Gray:
      Minimum:                   255.00 (1.0000)
      Maximum:                   255.00 (1.0000)
      Mean:                      255.00 (1.0000)
      Standard Deviation:          0.00 (0.0000)
  Filesize: 581
  Interlace: No
  Orientation: Unknown
  Background Color: white
  Border Color: #DFDFDF
  Matte Color: #BDBDBD
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl, you can do the following. It captures the numeric value after `minimum:` inside the block `Channel Statistics:` and prints it:

```
perl -0 -ne '/Channel Statistics:\s+Gray:\s+Minimum:\h+([\d.]+)/ && print $1,"\n"' file
```

**Output:** (for given example)

```
255.00
```

**Explanation:**

```
-0      # specifies the input record separator. If there are no digits, the null character is the separator. The whole file is read in a single string.
-n      # Iterate over the file
-e      # execute the command line
```

**Regex:**

```
/                           # regex delimiter
    Channel Statistics:     # literally
    \s+                     # 1 or more any kind of spaces
    Gray:                   # literally
    \s+                     # 1 or more any kind of spaces
    Minimum:                # literally
    \h+                     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
    (                       # start group 1
        [\d.]+              # 1 or more digit or dot
    )                       # end group
/                           # regex delimiter
```

Answer (score 0):

#### With `sed`

```
sed -rn 's/^\s+Minimum:\s+([0-9.]+).+$/\1/p' image.data
```

In slow-mo:

- `-r` tells `sed` we use th extened regexp "syntax"
- `-n` tells `sed` to not print non-matching lines
- `s/^\s+Minimum:\s+([0-9.]+).+$/\1/` matches your target line and replaces it with just the value you are after
- `p` tells `sed` to print the result

If you need to disambiguate by taking in account the content of previous lines, it is just slightly more complicated:

```
sed -r ':a;N;$!ba; s/^.*Gray:\s*\n\s+Minimum:\s+([0-9.]+).+$/\1/' image.data
```

where:

- `:a;N;$!ba;` is a loop in the `sed` language that loads the whole file at once
- `-n` is no longer necessary since there are no other lines we don't want to print
- the final `p` is no longer necessary either since we don't use `-n`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simplistic, assuming that the string 'Minimum:' occurs exactly once in your input:

```
awk '/Minimum:/ {print $2}'
```